# The modal pop up is not responsive. The website is responsive and the content inside the popup is responsive as well

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, popup

The popup itself does not resize and when I reduce the size of the browser to test, the popup is hidden and when I scroll, popup remains fixed. So, here are some of the codes.

So I'm using this `jquery.leanModal.min.js`

This is my HTML code:

```
<a id="modal_trigger" class="transition-effect btn" href="#modal"> 
<div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">   
<section class="popupBody">
<div class="user_login">
<form method="post">
 ........ and it continues for the sign up form
```

The CSS:

```
lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;

    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}

.popupContainer{
    position:absolute;

    width:50%;
    height: auto;
    left:45%;
    top:80px;
    background: #FFF;
    display : none;
    margin: auto;
}

.popupBody {
    padding:20px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid cyan;

}
```

Comment: here comes an adapted version to make it responsive https://gist.github.com/simogeo/3ae498745e68931030c39da5cdf0c46a. See also https://gist.github.com/simogeo/c94aa80be3194523b3a43948ce78ae4c

Answer (score 0):

Leanmodal doesn't seem very responsive on it's site.

You can try a more responsive popup library like jPopup(https://github.com/seahorsepip/jPopup) or write mediaqueries css for leanmodal.

Comment: Thanks. I've used css media queries and it works now.